# Propagate ChildComponent attribute of ParentComponent to another Child Component

Tags: angular

I have the following scenario:

AppComponent (parent):

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('preloader')
  preloader: MaterializePreloaderComponent;

  get getPreloader(): MaterializePreloaderComponent {
    return this.preloader;
  }

}
```

ChildComponent:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class ChildComponent {

  preloader: MaterializePreloaderComponent;

}
```

The ChildComponent is rendered inside a route-outlet inside the template of the AppComponent:

```
<router-outlet [preloader]="getPreloader"></router-outlet>
```

I got this error:

```
Expression 'getPreloader in AppComponent@13:15' has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '[object Object]' in [getPreloader in AppComponent@13:15]
```

I've read some stuff about this error, and it happens because the value of preloader change on parent after being propagated. Being so, seems like the workaround would be fire an event on a ngAfterViewInit method on AppComponent, so the view can be updated with the correct value of preloader attribute.

Anyway, I dont like this approach and dont know exacly how to do it, hope you guus can help me.

Comment: You have a [lot to read about](https://github.com/angular/angular/search?q=has+changed+after+it+was+checked&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93) that error message. Specifically I recommend you these two comments from [@pkozlowzki](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6005#issuecomment-165981565) and [@vicb](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5950#issuecomment-165526662). And second you [can't pass data](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4452) to child components loaded by routing.

Comment: Thats so sad to read :(